# Samba free space issue, dfree command not being called

Tags: 16.04, server, samba

I have a Samba server running Ubuntu 16.04.1 serving some btrfs subvolumes. These volumes have btrfs quotas set through `btrfs qgroup`.

In order to reflect the quota to the clients, I want to use a custom `dfree command`.

My problem is that Samba seems to never call my `dfree command`, and just shows the btrfs filesystem's available free space.

```
username@NAS:~$ smbd --version
Version 4.3.11-Ubuntu
```

My smb.conf:

```
[global]
max log size = 1000
usershare allow guests = yes
dns proxy = no
pam password change = yes
workgroup = WORKGROUP
map to guest = bad user
obey pam restrictions = yes
server role = standalone server
passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
passdb backend = tdbsam
encrypt passwords = yes
server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
log level = 10
syslog = 0
dfree cache time = 0

[printers]
comment = All Printers
browseable = no
path = /var/spool/samba
printable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = yes
create mask = 0700

# Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
# printer drivers
[print$]
comment = Printer Drivers
path = /var/lib/samba/printers
browseable = yes
read only = yes
guest ok = no

[username_backup]
path = /backup_tank/username
browsable = yes
force group = username
directory mode = 750
force user = username
guest ok = no
valid users = username
create mode = 650
writable = yes
security = user
dfree command = /usr/local/bin/df_btrfs
```

usr/local/bin/df_btrfs (owner root:root and 700 rights):

```
#!/bin/bash

STR=$(/bin/btrfs qgroup show -rF --raw /backup_tank/username/ | /usr/bin/tail -1)

SIZE=$(/usr/bin/expr `/bin/echo $STR | /usr/bin/cut -d \  -f 4` / 1024)
USED=$(/usr/bin/expr `/bin/echo $STR | /usr/bin/cut -d \  -f 2` / 1024)
AVAIL=$(/usr/bin/expr $SIZE - $USED)

/bin/echo $SIZE $AVAIL
```

When I run this script (as root because of the btrfs command), it gives me the right numbers, in the format expected by Samba:

```
username@NAS:~$ sudo /usr/local/bin/df_btrfs
734003200 196187016
```

What I've tried unsuccessfully (samba keeps giving me the same numbers, logs show no error or sign of the script being run):

- ```
  chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/df_btrfs
  ```
- Replace the `/usr/local/bin/df_btrfs` content with:

  ```
   #!/bin/bash

   /bin/echo "734003200 196187016"
  ```
- Replace the `dfree command` setting with

  ```
  dfree command = 734003200 196187016
  ```
- Replace the `dfree command` setting with a non existing file path

  ```
  dfree command = /usr/local/bin/df_btrfs_nonexistant
  ```

  (still no error in the logs even though this file doesn't exist)
- Trying the things above with `dfree command` in `[global]`

I restarted the smbd service between each try, and then even the server and client computer.

The only sign of the `dfree command` or `/usr/local/bin/df_btrfs` in smbd's logs are:

```
[2016/12/27 12:16:52.059912,  5, pid=23203, effective(0, 0), real(0, 0)] ../source3/param/loadparm.c:1325(free_param_opts)
doing parameter dfree command = /usr/local/bin/df_btrfs
doing parameter dfree cache time = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find description here and risky workaround:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1310792